# What is "for" in Ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

In Ruby:

```
for i in A do
    # some code
end
```

is the same as:

```
A.each do |i|
   # some code
end
```

`for` is not a kernel method:

- What exactly is "`for`" in ruby
- Is there a way to use other keywords to do similar things?

Something like:

```
 total = sum i in I {x[i]}
```

mapping to:

```
 total = I.sum {|i] x[i]}
```

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's almost syntax sugar. One difference is that, while `for` would use the scope of the code around it, `each` creates a separate scope within its block. Compare the following:

```
for i in (1..3)
  x = i
end
p x # => 3
```

versus

```
(1..3).each do |i|
  x = i
end
p x # => undefined local variable or method `x' for main:Object
```

Comment: Wow, so subtle, yet will become handy when I run into something like this. Thanks!

Comment: Actually your second example throws `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'i' for main:Object`. It's because you're missing a `do`.

Answer (score 14):

`for` is just syntax sugar for the `each` method. This can be seen by running this code:

```
for i in 1 do
end
```

This results in the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for 1:Fixnum
```

Comment: -1 because there is a difference between the two, and they are not always equivalent.

Answer (score 9):

For is just syntactic sugar.

From [the pickaxe](http://www.rubycentral.com/pickaxe/tut_expressions.html#UK):

> **For ... In**
>
> Earlier we said that the only built-in Ruby looping primitives were while and until. What's this ``for'' thing, then? Well, for is almost a lump of syntactic sugar. When you write
>
> ```
> for aSong in songList
>   aSong.play
> end
> ```
>
> Ruby translates it into something like:
>
> ```
> songList.each do |aSong|
>   aSong.play
> end
> ```
>
> The only difference between the for loop and the each form is the scope of local variables that are defined in the body. This is discussed on page 87.
>
> You can use for to iterate over any object that responds to the method each, such as an Array or a Range.
>
> ```
> for i in ['fee', 'fi', 'fo', 'fum']
>   print i, " "
> end
> for i in 1..3
>   print i, " "
> end
> for i in File.open("ordinal").find_all { |l| l =~ /d$/}
>   print i.chomp, " "
> end
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> fee fi fo fum 1 2 3 second third
> ```
>
> As long as your class defines a sensible each method, you can use a for loop to traverse it.
>
> ```
> class Periods
>   def each
>     yield "Classical"
>     yield "Jazz"
>     yield "Rock"
>   end
> end
>
>
> periods = Periods.new
> for genre in periods
>   print genre, " "
> end
> ```
>
> produces:
>
> ```
> Classical Jazz Rock
> ```

Ruby doesn't have other keywords for list comprehensions (like the sum example you made above).  `for` isn't a terribly popular keyword, and the method syntax ( `arr.each {}` ) is generally preferred.