# ruby: What's the meaning of keyword "in"

Tags: ruby

When I find the keyword "in" in ruby first time. I think maybe I can do that:
  1 in (0..10)
But it look like I cannot use it like that way.

Then I search it in ruby-lang.org, and google it. There is no answer!

What's the meaning of keyword "in" in ruby?

Comment: See also this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155462/what-is-for-in-ruby

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to do the following:

```
for i in 0..10 do
  puts i
end
```

The expression `1 in (0..10)` that you mention won't work because a constant (1) can't vary over a range - it's a constant! You need to name a variable before the `in` keyword.

Hope that helps.

See [this page](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Looping_with_for_and_the_Ruby_Looping_Methods) as well.

Comment: Thank you!
Because I come from F# and lisp. I always use "each" "map". I even forget the "for" loop keyword.

Comment: You can also use "for in"-loops in F#

Comment: Object#each is probably more Ruby-ish than for...in

Comment: To achieve the same result from 'for i in 0..10', one could use Fixnum#times i.e. '10.times do |i| ... end'. I think this is indeed more expressive and more "Ruby-ish".

Answer (score 0):

according to the pragmatic programmers book you se it as following

```
while *name*[, *name*]... in *expression* [do | :]
  body
end
```

so you use it in loops,
sorry if this is vague, but i have only started learning ruby.

Answer (score 0):

> I think maybe I can do that: 1 in (0..10) But it look like I cannot use it like that way

Now you can :)

Because Ruby introduced [pattern matching](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/master/syntax/pattern_matching_rdoc.html)

`1 in 0..10` is alias of this code:

```
case 1
in 0..10
  true
else
  false
end
```

Using `1 in 0..10` expression you can check if one expression matches another