# What does the ruby method "in" do?

Tags: ruby

It's a bit hard to search for it.  This might actually be a Rails method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1011282/ruby-whats-the-meaning-of-keyword-in

Comment: I know `in` is a keyword, used in loops, is it a method too? If so, can you give us an example of usage?

Comment: Sorry for the close vote, didn't read the comment and didn't know about `Date#in`

Comment: @Marc-André no worries.  not sure if this one should stay open but I guess the since alias could be good to know

Comment: Please provide more context to this "in"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know what any method does, just do "ri the_method" from the shell. In this case, "ri in" reveals `Date#in`. "ri Date.in" gives:

> Alias for #since

In turn, "ri Date.since" gives:

> Converts Date to a Time (or DateTime if necessary) with the time
>       portion set to the beginning of the day (0:00) and then adds the
>       specified number of seconds

And yes, it's in ActiveSupport.

Comment: Weird.  I don't get that at all.  "ri in" just lists a ton of methods. "ri Date.since" gives "Nothing known about Date.since"

Comment: Wrong, he means the `in` in `for project in @projects`, which is in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

"in" is used as an alternative to the array.each do |a| syntax

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

for a in array
 puts a
end

1
2
3
4
```

Comment: ah yes, so used to each.  don't think i've ever used "in" in ruby

Comment: -1. This answer is about the `in` keyword. The OP asked about the `in` method. Keywords and methods are two completely different things and have absolutely nothing to do with each other.