# Ruby: difference between @cars.each do |car| and for car in @cars do

Tags: ruby, car-analogy

(Sorry for the newbie question.) In Ruby, what is the difference between the loops:

```
@cars.each do |car|
```

and

```
for car in @cars do
```

?

is there a difference in efficiency, or why do we need two (or more) ways to express the same thing? The second way seems more elegant/natural to me, but I may be missing some crucial observation, why the first may be the better choice.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

More people use the `@cars.each` notation because that generalizes to other methods (like `#inject`, `#each_with_index`, `#map`, etc, as well as non-iterator callbacks).

for/in is mainly just syntactic sugar for `#each`.  The main difference in how the two work is in variable scoping:

```
irb> @cars = %w{ ford chevy honda toyota }
#=> ["ford", "chevy", "honda", "toyota"]
irb> @cars.each { |car| puts car }
ford
chevy
honda
toyota
#=> ["ford", "chevy", "honda", "toyota"]
irb> car
NameError: undefined local variable or method `car` for #<Object:0x399770 @cars=["ford", "chevy", "honda", "toyota"]>
        from (irb):3
        from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>`
irb> for car in @cars
     puts car.reverse
     end
drof
yvehc
adnoh
atoyot
#=> ["ford", "chevy", "honda", "toyota"]
irb> car
#=> "toyota"
```

for/in leaves the iterator variable in scope afterwards, while `#each` doesn't.

Personally, I never use ruby's for/in syntax.

Comment: +1 : that's strange. C# loopvar does not out-live the for construct. Anyways all the more reason to stick to each

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155462/what-is-for-in-ruby/155543#155543

Comment: Ruby scoping is pretty bad, the perl equivalent of that will not even compile with strict.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is just syntactic sugar. It is functionally equivalent, and I am not aware of any implementation difference in the interpreter.

Note - you can lose the 'do' on the second one.