# difference between "each .. do" or "for .. in" loops in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is “for” in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155462/what-is-for-in-ruby)

Hey. My question is if these loops are the same when I iterate through an Array. Thx for your time!

```
<% for track in @tracks %>
```

or

```
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
```

Comment: Did you try it to see what happens?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155462/what-is-for-in-ruby

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are different (although it may not matter for your purposes).

`for` doesn't create a new scope:

```
blah = %w(foo bar baz)
for x in blah do
   z = x
end
puts z # "baz"
puts x # "baz"
```

`.each` creates a new scope for the block:

```
blah.each { |y| a = y }
puts a # NameError
puts y # NameError
```

Comment: What do you mean by new scope?

Comment: @Sam: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(programming)  Notice how the `x` and `z` variables in my example can be accessed after the `for` loop, but `a` and `y` cannot be accessed outside of the block passed to `each`.

Answer (score 3):

#### No

For the most part, you probably won't see any differences, but things are quite different in those two cases.

In one case, you have a loop directly in Ruby syntax, in the other case a data structure traversal is periodically yielding to a block.

- **return** may work differently. If the outer code is in a **lambda** then **return** will return from the lambda within the loop but if executed within a block it will return from the enclosing method outside the lambda.
- The **lexical scope** of identifiers created within the loop is different. (On general principles you really shouldn't create things inside a structured language feature and then use them later outside but this is possible in Ruby with the loop and not with the block.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference here. Just a difference in syntax.

What could make this different is adding elements to the block such as a counter, or more advanced features.

```
<% @tracks.each do |i, track| -%>
    <% #i is your counter... just and example of adding more information in the block %>
<% end -%>
```